# How to Restrict Previous & Next Post Link to Posts of Same Category?

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy, pagination, navigation

I am using a category to segregate all posts of that one category to feel like a complete website sub-section. So the main posts feed is using a plugin to hide posts of that category, and I am using a menu item in the header to link to a page showing posts of only that category.

However, once you click on a post, the next and previous will browse through all posts regardless of categories and I would want it to remain within the context of that category.

Likewise, in the full regular feed, once a post is open I would like the navigation to exclude that category.

Comment: Are you using `query_posts` or a custom `WP_Query` to display your posts?

Comment: I am not intentionally using anything, i.e. I'm using it out of the box. I am using some plugins but none that affect the display of posts.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose from any of the following functions:**

1. `get_next_post_link();`
2. `next_post_link();`
3. `get_previous_post_link();`
4. `previous_post_link();`

**Parameters are as follows (in respective order):**

> 1. `@param` `string`       `$format`         **Optional.** Link anchor format. **Default** '« %link'.
> 2. `@param` `string`       `$link`           **Optional.** Link permalink format. **Default** '%title'.
> 3. `@param` `bool`         `$in_same_term`   **Optional.** Whether link should be in a same taxonomy term. **Default** `false`.
> 4. `@param` `array|string` `$excluded_terms` **Optional.** `Array` or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs. **Default** `empty`.
> 5. `@param` `string`       `$taxonomy`       **Optional.** Taxonomy, if `$in_same_term` is `true`. **Default** 'category'.
>
> `@return` `string` The link URL of the next post in relation to the
>   current post.

Optionally, you could do more with your pagination if you opted for more labor. You could use `get_next_post();` or `get_previous_post();` These two functions would allow you to retrieve the entire next/previous post object. You could then retrieve post meta, featured image, post format, post excerpt, etc.

**Parameters are as follows (in respective order):**

> 1. `@param` `bool`        `$in_same_term`   **Optional.** Whether post should be in a same taxonomy term. **Default** `false`.
> 2. `@param` `array|string` `$excluded_terms` **Optional.** `Array` or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs. **Default** `empty`.
> 3. `@param` `string`       `$taxonomy`       **Optional.** Taxonomy, if `$in_same_term` is `true`. **Default** 'category'.
>
> `@return` `null|string|WP_Post` `Post object` if successful. `Null` if
>   `global $post` is not set. `Empty` `string` if no corresponding post
>   exists.

All of this (and more) can be found in `./wp-includes/link-template.php`

Comment: Thank you. I am only new to Wordpress and rely mostly on plugins. What I'm unsure on is where to use the four functions you first mention and how do I restrict what I want to only a certain category?

Comment: I would search your currently activated WordPress theme for the usage of those functions. Find their usage of those functions and replace with your own usage of these functions. Depending on how the theme was crafted those functions could be called in a number of different ways. I would check: `single.php`, `singular.php`, `page.php`, etc. Now I would also recommend using a [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) to make your changes, so that your changes aren't lost when the theme gets updated.